# show multiple select box value with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am a php developer and using an multiple select box , i want when we select a multiple 
option from the select box then value of every select box should be display in text box how 
can i do this with the help of jquery please help if anybody have solution of this
thank's

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#multiSelect').change(function() {
    $('#txtSelect').val($('#multiSelect').val());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off a hint from [jMar's blog](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html):

```
$("#multipleSelect").change(function() {
  $("#textBox").val("");
  $("#multipleSelect option:selected").each(function(i) {
    if (i > 0)
      $("#textBox").val($("#textBox").val() + ", " + $(this).text());
    else
      $("#textBox").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

If you don't need the commas/separators, it's actually just:

```
$("#multipleSelect").change(function() {
  $("#textBox").val($("#multipleSelect option:selected").text());
});
```

[*Fiddle* with it over at jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mefzJ/3/)